# PHP URL Rewrite doesn't work on specific server

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

My URL rewrite works perfectly on my testing server, but not on the live server.

I contacted the support team and they told me that mod_rewrite is already enabled on my hosting plan.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ work-tag.php?d=$1&t=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ work-tag.php?d=$1&t=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ work.php?d=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ work.php?d=$1
```

Anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What result are you getting instead? Did you look into the RewriteLog?

Comment: 404 - page not found!

Comment: If mod_rewrite was disabled you'd get a 500, so the rules aren't triggering. Have you installed in a subfolder or something like that?

Comment: @Niels, yes, the site is installed in a sub folder and the domain name is being forwarded to that sub folder. Should we move the site to the root and disable domain forwarding to solve that issue? Thanks

Comment: I get 404 when I try to use friendly URLs on that server. http://tinyurl.com/brekjx4

Comment: .htaccess is seen as I tried to redirect the site to a different url in .htaccess and it worked, but url rewriting didn't.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, but if you was asked about turned mode_rewrite - check it. I was told the same but I didn't find my htaccess working so I checked it by myself. And I found that mod_rewrite was still off.

```
 phpinfo();
```

and have a look at the "Loaded Modules". If you see it so the server is not a problem. And need to go futher.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is the phpinfo page http://tinyurl.com/dy7563s - couldn't find mod_rewrite in there! it's not enabled, right?

Comment: The server is running PHP over CGI so it can't see anything about Apache. Like I said above, the module is enabled otherwise you'd get a 500 error on the commands.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by adding the following line as a friend suggested.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Thanks for your follow-up guys :)